# A better way to process dynamic content urls than .php?id=?

Tags: php, database, web, hosting

Ive just launched a new blog built from scratch, and currently process each blog post with the following url format

www.domain.com/article.php?id=1

Reading online it seems this style of URL is not good and I can see why, its not descriptive in the slightest. I was wondering what common ways exist to process urls for dynamic content like blog posts that are easier to use, ideally without having .php and setting GET values?

Comment: Look into so called clean urls for whatever web server you are using. Apache uses mod_rewrite

Comment: The benefit of your way is that you can bookmark a page or send a direct link. Other methods may not work like that.